# Asynchronous JavaScript workarounds

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, callback, mongoose

I am doing some work with MEANjs to help get some experience with it, and I'm having issues with Mongoose's asynchronous function calls. I'm having to build work-arounds because I'm hell bent on coding in a synchronous mindset. Am I doing all this wrong?

**Example 1: Invoke next action at end of asynchronous callback**

For example, imagine a JavaScript game (MEANjs) that has server-side combat code. This code will grab any AI enemy entities that have battle commands (such as Attack, Shoot Fireball, etc) and process those commands. However, the very first thing that needs to take place is looking up the list of available abilities from the MongoDB so that we know what these battle commands need to do. For example, if an enemy wants to execute their "Spit Fire IV" ability, the returned information would let us know how much damage this causes, etc.

This would require a call to Mongoose's model.find which is an asynchronous call. The callback would populate an object with all ability information that can be used later in the battle command processor. (This is the troublesome part).

Once model.find's callback has invoked, the data will be stored, and the processCombat() function will be executed at the end of this callback. No problem here, right, is this best practice? I have in the past just put a setTimeout after calling this type of asynchronous call to ensure that the object is populated, but that seems like a poor design.

**Example 2: Passing data to asynchronous methods called iteratively**

Imagine now you're in this combat processor method. You have a model.find to get the set of enemies that must be processed, and within that find's callback, you must perform a model.findOne to get that enemy's targeted player and execute certain things in its callback such as validating the combat command, changing the player's health, updating the enemy to let it know that it has processed its combat command, etc.

Pseudo code: For each enemy that is ready to perform combat, 1) get the enemy, 2) get the player it is targeting in combat, 3) update the player and enemy data to complete combat, i.e. player loses some health.

```
Enemy.find(... function(err,enemies) {
    var enemyList = [];
    for(var i=0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
        enemyList.push({
          playerID: enemies[i].combatTargetID,
          enemy: enemies[i],
          processed: false
        });

        Player.findOne({_id: enemies[i].combatTargtID}, function(err,player) {
            var enemy = null;
            for(var j = 0; j < enemyList.length; j++) {
                if(player.id === enemyList[j].playerID && enemyList[j].processed === false) {
                    enemy = enemyList[j].enemy;
                    enemyList[j].processed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //do things with enemy and player!
        });
    }
});
```

The important parts are with enemyList being populated and then its usage within the asynchronous callback. It is very likely, since findOne is asynchronous, that enemyList will be fully populated by the time the first findOne callback executes, but despite that, it wouldn't need to be fully populated for it to validly execute (i.e. the target object used in the callback would be available at the time of executing findOne). Once the findOne is executd, it iterates through the list of enemies to find its own playerID that hasn't been currently processed -- keep in mind multiple enemies can target the same player, so there is a need for a processed variable in addition to simply looking up the playerID.

Is there a better way?

A caveat to this: What if multiple callbacks are being invoked at the same time. It's possible to create a race condition where multiple instances are on the same line, so using the processed variable wouldn't be 100% perfect..

(Sorry if this is a crazy question, but this type of programming is weird and I feel like I'm designing against it rather than with it, so I'm looking for insights)

Comment: ah crap haha, it's too early. i meant asynchronous every time i said synchronous.

Comment: No worries. :) You pretty much have two options, Use promises, or a counter with callbacks, which would you prefer? I tend to lean more toward promises because error handling with promises is usually easier.

Comment: alright, flipped all those words. hopefully it makes a little more sense now

Comment: @KevinB promises/callbacks are fine solutions, but my main concern is seen in example 2 where data basically needs to be passed in and used by the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case i would break the process down into several functions that return promises and then chain them all together.

```
function getEnemies (obj) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    Enemy.find(... function(err,enemies) {
      if (err) {throw err;}
      obj.enemies = enemies.map(function (enemy) {
        return {
          playerID: enemy.combatTargetID,
          enemy: enemy,
          processed: false
        };
      });
      resolve(obj);
    });
  });
}

function getPlayers (obj) {
  return Promise.all(obj.enemies.map(function (enemy) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      Player.findOne({_id: enemy.combatTargtID}, function(err,player) {
        if (err) {throw err;}
        enemy.player = player;
        resolve();
      });
    })
  }).then(function () {
    return obj;
  });
}

function doWork() {
  getEnemies()
    .then(getPlayers)
    .then(function (obj) {
      console.log(obj); // do stuff with enemies and players here
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is pretty cool. I didn't consider using promises like this! I will give this a shot. In fact, I think this is exactly what I originally was looking for- basically a callback on the callback function itself. Promise.all even covers handling multiple iterative callbacks, sweeeeeet.

Comment: Probably a bit too complex for my answer, but, it would likely be more efficient if you can find a way to get all needed players with one query while still being able to associate them to each enemy. for example, using a `$in: ['playerid','playerid']`

Comment: True- in this case it may be possible to perform a better query, but I'm sure there would be cases where that approach would not be feasible and Promise.all would be required to support it. Can you recommend a good promise library that works well with Node? I'm seeing good things on Q

Comment: i use the --harmony flag to get promises natively, but blurbird and Q are both good alternatives. I usually use bluebird.